# How to configure Qemu to get more speed out of qemu-arm-static

Tags: qemu

When I configure like shown below and then compile, then the resulting qemu-arm performs many (about 20 to 40) times worse than the qemu-arm-static that came with Ubuntu 18.04.3 (AMD64).

I used the same branch (stable-2.11) as the version that came with Ubuntu.

How could I configure to get more performance?

./configure --static --target-list=arm-softmmu,arm-linux-user --extra-cflags=-O3 --extra-cxxflags=-O3 --extra-ldflags=-O3

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if -O3 is a good idea -- you could check whether the Ubuntu package build uses that; I suspect it uses the default -O2 instead. In fact a good first step would be to build the Ubuntu package without any changes (ie get the package source with 'apt source qemu' and build it as an Ubuntu package) and check that it has the same performance you're seeing with the shipped binary version.

If the package you build doesn't have the same performance as the Ubuntu-built binary: then something weird is going on, which you'd need to investigate.

If the package you build does have the same performance as the Ubuntu-built binary (ie better than whatever you're building now): then the difference is somewhere in either how the Ubuntu packaging is configuring QEMU, or in the build environment it is using, or in some set of patches it's using that aren't in the branch you're currently building. You could try to narrow down what the difference is.

Other than that, a general note is that 2.11 is now a pretty old version of QEMU, and there have been performance improvements upstream since 2.11. But they're not 20-40x, so you should definitely try to identify why you're not getting the same performance as the Ubuntu package binary first.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Infact I compiled 2.11.2 whereas the binary version is 2.11.0. That may or may not explain the performance difference. I just compiled 3.1 (latest on github) and got similar performance as the shipped binary. Will check on monday at work if I get sufficient performance in the environment there.

Comment: Latest release is 4.1, by the way (just came out last week).